# How do I find a transformation from a triangular region in the xy plane to a region in the uv plane?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been tasked with computing the following double integral in the region R by using a change of variable to a region S in the uv plane:

$$\iint_R xy-y^2 dA$$

The region R is bounded by the following lines:

$$y=2x, y=\frac{1}{2}x, y-2=1-x$$

Everything in my textbook and online already has the transformations given, and I don't know how to properly set up the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

- $u=\frac y x \implies \frac12 \le u \le 2$
- $v=x+y \implies 0\le v\le 3$

with
$$du\,dv= \left(-\frac y {x^2}-\frac1x\right)dx\, dy=-\frac{x+y}{x^2} dx\,dy$$

and since

- $y=ux$
- $y=v-x \implies x=\frac{v}{u+1} \quad y=\frac{uv}{u+1}$

therefore

$$\iint_R xy-y^2 dA = \int_{\frac12}^2 du\int_{0}^3 \frac{x^2(y^2-xy)}{x+y} dv= \int_{\frac12}^2 du\int_{0}^3 \frac{\frac{u^3v^4}{(u+1)^4}(u-1)}{v} dv= $$

$$=\int_{\frac12}^2 du\int_{0}^3 \frac{u^3v^3(u-1)}{(u+1)^4} dv$$

Comment: thanks for the response! alright, so that gives me u=G(x, y) and v=H(x, y), but i'm still a bit confused. is this a transformation of a triangular region into a quadrilateral region? and how would I solve this system of equations for x=g(u, v) and y=h(u, v)?

Comment: @TaylorRose I add something on that.

Comment: That seems way out of my league, and I found a different transformation that makes sense to me, but I really appreciate the help. It definitely clarified things for me :)

Comment: @TaylorRose What transformation have you used?